# webservice not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jquery

I am working on an ASP.NET web application.

I want to use Jquery ajax to call a web service. The webservice will return a string.

This is my webservice:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetStringForPerson(string Personname, int StartYear, int EndYear)
    {
        string S = "Hello" + Personname + " You where born between " + StartYear + " and " + EndYear;
        return S;
    }
}
```

And the Ajax function that will call it:

```
function GetStringForPerson(Name) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Service/MyWebService.asmx/GetStringForPerson",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'Personname':Name, 'StartYear':'2001', 'EndYear':'2005'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

But when I call it, I am getting an error 500, "internal Server Error"

I placed a break point in the web method but it is not reaching it.

What might be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: This is the article I continue to refer to when using jQuery with ASMX web services - http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One bug that I see is the `Name` variable, is not send as string and not as variable as it is.
So change this line as :

```
data: "{'Personname':'" + Name + "', 'StartYear':'2001', 'EndYear':'2005'}",
```

Comment: @youssef if the name contains any character like `'` it may break your line, think also to encode it using the `encodeURIComponent`